# 'forkdepth' has value '-2' error message when running nytprof perl profiler

Tags: perl, profiler, devel-nytprof

Though, I set variable NYTPROF to "forkdepth:1", When i try to nytprofmerge the profiler outputs for my forked children along with it's parent, I get a message that says:

Reading nytprof.13232.out.21321
Option 'forkdepth' has value '-2' in nytprof.13232.out.21321 which differs from the previous value '-1'; this implies inconsistent profiles and thus garbage results.

Does anyone know a fix or why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a guess that that's a bug in nytprofmerge and can be ignored.
Feel free to [file a bug report](https://github.com/timbunce/devel-nytprof/issues). (A small script that reproduces the problem would be super helpful).